# Akavache BlobCache.Secure is null on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, akavache

I am trying to use Akavache to store data securely in my Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android project. All seems to be OK on iOS, but it fails on Android saying `BlobCache.Secure` is null.

Before accessing the cache I set it up with:

```
BlobCache.ApplicationName = "AppAkavache";
BlobCache.EnsureInitialized();
```

I have tried reference it directly: `BlobCache.Secure` (`Secure null`) or by setting it up using my IoC

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ISecureBlobCache>(BlobCache.Secure);

public CacheStorage(ISecureBlobCache blobCache){
    var test = blobCache; // still null
}
```

But the end result is the same. The only cache that is available on BlobCache on Android, is InMemoryCache.

Comment: Found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Still having this problem.

Comment: Did you ensure that Xamarin Linker doesn't remove Akavache.Sqlite3 as described in here: https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache#handling-xamarin-linker